# Visual Studio 2019 Event Handler Auto-complete suggestion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I found that when I am trying to attach an event handler and I type += VS2019 will offer an event handler name and (Press TAB to insert).  I'd like to turn this off, but I cannot find any setting in intellisense to configure it.

[image]

It will also overlay other intellisense information.
[image]

What setting controls this behavior?  I'd like to disable it.

Comment: It seems that it cannot be disabled. There is no relevant setting in the intellisense. Maybe you can suggest a feature on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8).